# Fade UICollectionViewCells with overlap goes wrong

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I have an UICollectionView with some UICollectionViewCells. Cells are supposed to overlap each other, but also to fade a bit based on their position. See below the result:[image]

How can I avoid those corners to be visible? (top between 3 and 4, or 4 and 5, or all the right side between 5 and 6). They should overlap, but that should not affect the image.

Comment: This is because of transparency as they fade - the two lighter colours superimposed create a darker colour. One way around this would be to use a lighter colour rather than alpha fade.

Comment: Lighter color as in an overlay? Tried it but in brings problems as the shape of the image is not a square and the it would have kind of the same effect but in another zone. Do you think of something else?

Comment: Can you set the background colour of the cells themselves?

Comment: No, because the overlap will look strange as it will be a colored square around my image.

Comment: Ah yes I see. How are you creating the irregular shape?

Comment: It’s an asset, .png

Comment: Can you edit the png in image editing software to remove transparency (alpha) and make it just a colour with no transparency?

Comment: You mean to have a version of the picture for each “shade”? That would be possible. There are other workarounds as well for this, but I’m interested into how to fix it despite what image would be used in there. Something like make apply the alpha, but don’t make visible the cell from behind

Comment: Yeah there are probably a few ways - I'm not familiar with other possibilities I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you! Let’s see how the question will evolve. I really hope that someone will rock our minds with something that we didn’t thought of.

Comment: There might be a way to draw a custom view with bezier paths or core graphics, but I’m not familiar with these. Would be good to find out a good way to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a fade effect I would use an overlay like this:

- Save the original image in a variable to be able to reset the process for different alpha values
- Draw a shape that has same color as background (color alpha should be proportional with the item position) on top of your current image
- Replace the result image with your current one

I will give you an example to illustrate better:

```
private UIImage baseImage; 

private UIImage ChangeImageColor(UIImage image, nfloat alpha, UIColor color)
{
   var alphaColor = color.ColorWithAlpha(alpha);

   if(baseImage == null)
   {
      baseImage = image;       
   }
   else
   {
      image = baseImage;
   }

   UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(image.Size, false, UISCreen.MainScreen.Scale);

   var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
   alphaColor.SetFill();

   context.TranslateCTM(0, image.Size.Height);
   context.ScaleCTM(new nfloat(1.0), new nfloat(-1.0));
   context.SetBlendMode(CGBlendMode.Lighten);

   var rect = new CGRect(0, 0, image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height);
   context.DrawImage(rect, image.CGImage);

   context.SetBlendMode(CGBlendMode.SourceAtop);
   context.AddRect(rect);
   context.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.Fill);

   image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

   return image;
}
```